# How to filter multiple records from an Array?

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

Here i write simple filter function which can filter Rec
_pagedItems:any[];
allItems   its contain Array

```
someval(value){
    if(value.length>=5){
        this._pagedItems= this.allItems.find(e=>e.uniqueid ==value || e.name == value );

        if(this._pagedItems == undefined){
            this.pagedItems=null;
        }
        else{
            this.pagedItems=[];
            this.pagedItems.push(this._pagedItems);
        }
    }
}
```

If i Remove || from the code Like   `this._pagedItems= this.allItems.find(e=>e.uniqueid == value );`  its working

Comment: Try to use `?` in your question (assuming you are asking something). Not clear what problem you have.

Comment: @dfsq Ok i added ?

Comment: @dfsq  did u have any Idea about how to search for multipu Rec

Comment: can you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: I have some data i wana 2 filter that data based on my Requirement Like  I Have ID=1,Fname=John LName=Lime ;   If i search Lime or John i want that Particular Record

Comment: This is Search functionality...But Problem is search text is not search all the Items wen its under Pagination

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong Array-function. .find() only returns the first item. You have to use .filter() instead. The you get an array of all matching entries.

```
 someval(value){
  if(value.length>=5){
        this._pagedItems= this.allItems.filter(e=>e.uniqueid ==value || e.name == value );

        if(this._pagedItems == undefined){
            this.pagedItems=null;
        }
        else{
            this.pagedItems=[];
            this.pagedItems.push(this._pagedItems);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you go. This should solve your problem. If this answer helped you, please don't forget to mark it as solution.

Comment: its not filtering its throughing all the dats

Comment: Can you please post your JSON-Object? What do you mean by "throughing"? No outcome or to many objects in the final list?